# My Villagers won't breed

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My villager breeder won't work.
I've made a villager breeder and I have about 8 villagers in it, I've fed the villagers with a few stacks of carrots, potatoes, beets and bread. The villagers are  displaying heart particles but don't produce baby villagers. 
I have one bucket of water on the ground below streaming the villagers into a trading station (obviously there are no villagers to stream) and I was wondering if this prevents the villagers to breed (like other mob spawns).

Answer (score 2):

Water on the ground does not prevent [villager breeding](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Breeding).

The fact that you have hearts means the [villagers are willing to breed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Villager#Willingness).  Unlike some of the animals, when villagers display hearts, they don't immediately seek another to mate with.  They take their time.  Even when two villagers are looking at each other, both with hearts, they don't always breed.

You probably just have to wait for them to breed.  One thing to check for, make sure that you are not just accidentally suffocating/killing the babies.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I'll look for the suffocation. My villagers are sitting on a fence post surrounded by cobble walls which is designed so that only baby villagers can fall through the gap. Also I have left it running for about 2 hours to no avail. I've removed all the doors around the breeder as well and there are no other villages nearby. I truly think that I have followed every rule but without success.

Comment: I recommend editing the question to include more information.  A few screen shots of the build would let us know what you are dealing with.  If you are seeing hearts, it is probably built properly. They are willing which means they recognize the village doesn't have enough and are trying to breed.

Answer (score 0):

Are there enough beds? Villagers only breed of there are more beds than villagers.

Comment: OP asked this question 3 years ago, so before the 1.14 update. Prior to 1.14, villagers did not require beds to breed.

Answer (score -1):

I thought mine weren’t breeding but they were drowning in water. After I got that fixed I had to put tons and tons of carrots and potatoes in there for them to breed. Now they won’t stop coming.